# Trying to put Feyman Diagram side by side horizontally w/ "+" in between.

Tags: diagrams, feynman, tikz-feynman

So i've been trying several threads in this forum on how to make my feynman diagrams look side by side. The problem is that no thing seems to work, this is how my two diagram look: 
[image]

and this is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\feynmandiagram [large, vertical= b to b1] {
a [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [anti fermion] b --  [charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] b1 [dot],
c [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [ fermion] b,
b1 -- [double,with arrow=0.5,edge label=$\mathcal{P}$] i2,
b2 -- [anti fermion,edge label=$N$] i2,
b3 -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] i2,
b1 -- [charged scalar,edge label=$\pi^0$] i3,
}; 

\feynmandiagram [large, vertical=b to b1] {
a [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [anti fermion] b  -- [charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] b1 [blob] ,
c [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [ fermion] b,

i4 -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] b1,
b1 -- [fermion, bend right=10, edge label = $Hadrons$] i5,
b1 -- [charged boson,edge label=$\pi^0$] i7,
};
\caption{\label{fig:fi} Semi inclusive COH + DIS + RES $\pi^0$ 
 production.}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to put them side by side with a "+" sign in between them. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perhaps simplest way is to use the `inline` option and to put the diagrams in a math environment (because of the + and spacing).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\[
\feynmandiagram [large, vertical= b to b1,inline=(b1.base)] {
a [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [anti fermion] b --  [charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] b1 [dot],
c [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [ fermion] b,
b1 -- [double,with arrow=0.5,edge label=$\mathcal{P}$] i2,
b2 -- [anti fermion,edge label=$N$] i2,
b3 -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] i2,
b1 -- [charged scalar,edge label=$\pi^0$] i3,
}; 
+
\feynmandiagram [large, vertical=b to b1,inline=(b1.base)] {
a [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [anti fermion] b  -- [charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] b1 [blob] ,
c [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [ fermion] b,

i4 -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] b1,
b1 -- [fermion, bend right=10, edge label = $Hadrons$] i5,
b1 -- [charged boson,edge label=$\pi^0$] i7,
};
\]
\caption{\label{fig:fi} Semi inclusive COH + DIS + RES $\pi^0$ 
 production.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, this is now at least your third question here, but so far you have not given any feedback on the answers you received. It would be great if you could do that.

Comment: Yes, true. I've been quite caught on with my thesis and forgot to give feedback. So far is been of great! The help here provided the three times is indeed useful. Without this site i wouldn't be able to learn proper latex.

Comment: @spacecatbro What I mean is that, if the solution worked for you, you may accept them. Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This makes it clear(er) to others that a solution works.

Comment: Excellent. Veryyyyy good and I upvote your answer. But can I also try to draw it if I can draw your picture with a different code?

Comment: @Sebastiano Scusi, I do not understand the question. The nice diagrams are from the OP, all I did is to put them in  a `\[...\]` environment and to use the inline option, which is explained in section 3.2.1 of the manual.

Comment: @marmot I wanted to make a new one. Nothing will be for the next time. I would like to learn this too. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano My learning curve with this is very flat and I often find it more convenient to place the vertices by hand. Overall tikz-feynman is a great package, but the placement algorithms are a bit weird (and require lualatex, which is why you need to convert them to pdf before submitting them to the arXiv).